# How to create a CSS3 animation that resembles an image fill up effect?

Tags: css, css-animations

Many preloaders fill up an image from bottom to top like [this example](http://buildinternet.com/live/imagefill/simple.html).

How would one create an animation based off a single image in CSS to show the fill up effect? I have tried with the following code but this just produces a image sliding effect and not a fill up effect.

By fill up effect what I mean is that the actual image slowly fills up a frame (like water filling up a tank).

```css
.frame {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.frame img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  animation: fill-up 3s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes fill-up {
  to {
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
  <img src='http://buildinternet.com/live/imagefill/dude.jpg' />
</div>
```

> **Note:** The images used in the answer are **not my own**. They were taken from [Build Internet Site](http://buildinternet.com/live/imagefill/simple.html).

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: I don't understand why the down votes?

Comment: I guess this is just because the Q is really too broad, since you're asking more for a generic tutorial ("Various methods of Web animations using CSS/SVG/JavaScript/Fortran") rather than a solution for [a *particular/specific* programming problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I did not down-vote but I voted for closing it as "too-broad".

Comment: The first one can be done using pure CSS itself. In the second one, I don't see any animation at all (it starts off as a large image and then quickly snaps to a smaller one). If you can narrow down your question to just the first animation (and also post some code that you tried - this is not mandatory but without it your question would be downvoted more and closed) then I can provide the answer.

Comment: @Harry Thanks for the tips, I just updated the question.

Comment: @Wonka: I've added an answer because I felt this question would be useful for others in future but as I said in my previous comment, you should really consider improving the question (like say include a clear explanation of what you are trying to achieve instead of having people check an external website, include some code that you tried etc). Else, the question is very likely to get closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an image fill-up animation similar to the one available [here](http://buildinternet.com/) (that uses jQuery for animation) is possible using CSS3 animations. It just needs two containers for the image and the height of one to be animated from to 0 to full height.

The following is how this animation is created:

- One parent container element whose height, width are equal to (or greater than) that of the image
- One second level container element which is positioned absolutely with respect to the bottom of the parent. The initial height of this element is set to 0 and the animation on this element produces the fill-up effect.
- The image  that is also positioned absolutely with respect to the bottom of the top level container.
- The second level container has `overflow: hidden` so that the other portions of the image do not show (they get clipped). As the height of the second level container is animated, more and more of the image become visible.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
}
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: fill-up 3s ease infinite;  
}
.frame img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
@keyframes fill-up {
  to {
    height: 600px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='frame'>
    <img src='http://buildinternet.com/live/imagefill/dude.jpg' />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As you could see from the above snippet, it doesn't have the frame visible before the image starts to fill up the frame. If that is also needed like in the linked website then it is tough to achieve with a single image. You would need two different image elements, where, one is the frame whose fill is transparent (so that the actual image positioned behind it can show through) and the other is the actual image. For this animation, we need one extra second level container for the frame. Below is a sample demo.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
}
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.frame:nth-child(2) {
  bottom: 35px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: fill-up 3s ease infinite;
}
.frame:nth-child(2) img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
@keyframes fill-up {
  to {
    height: 600px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='frame'>
    <img src='http://buildinternet.com/live/imagefill/dudeframe.png' />
  </div>
  <div class='frame'>
    <img src='http://buildinternet.com/live/imagefill/dude.jpg' />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The other thing we see in that linked website is that the fill happens at an angle. If that is also required then a `skew` transform should be added to the second level container (the one that has the image and not the frame). Since a transform is added to the parent, the image will also get skewed. So, a reverse transform should be added to the `img` element to make it appear normal.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
}
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.frame:nth-child(2) {
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 0px;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: fill-up 3s ease infinite;  
}
.frame:nth-child(2) img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 22px;
  transform: skewY(10deg);
}
@keyframes fill-up {
  to {
    height: 600px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='frame'>
    <img src='http://buildinternet.com/live/imagefill/dudeframe.png' />
  </div>
  <div class='frame'>
    <img src='http://buildinternet.com/live/imagefill/dude.jpg' />
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** The images used in the answer are **not my own**. They were taken from [Build Internet Site](http://buildinternet.com/live/imagefill/simple.html).

Comment: Harry, this is definitely the best way I found to achieve it in CSS3 alone :) Thank you for the amazing answer!